# Use image file from "Assets.xcassets" for changing iOS app icon programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiapplication, appicon

I'm trying to develop Icon Changing feature and I was going to use images from `Assets.xcassets` as app icon image.

I tried changing app icon using `setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)` after adding `CFBundleAlternateIcons` data to `info.plist`
But Xcode and iOS System cannot detect image file from `Assets.xcassets`.
I want to use image from `Assets.xcassets` as App icon. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic App Icon"?  At what stage do you intend to change icons?

Comment: @ElTomato I meant "Changing app icon programmatically" And I want to do that task by user interaction. 
Such as "App icon changes when user press certain button"

Sorry for lack of information

Comment: I have seen the same topic a few weeks ago.  I think the answer was no.  You may want to run a search for yourself, though.

Comment: I hoped there’s some way to do that. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use assets for that. But if your purpose is to adapt images for devices. Just add a suffix ( for example -@1x.png , -@2x.png, -@3x.png)

[Check this link for details](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the AppIcon image (in your "main" `.xcassets` bundle) with `setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)`, you should:

> Specify nil if you want to display the app’s primary icon

The alternate icons should live outside of any `.xcassets` bundle. As you mentioned, it seems those aren't supported for setting alternate icons.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname